# How to do a batch input from a web server?

Tags: batch, script, webserver, web-crawler

I am trying to load a protein structure file (e.g. [this](https://files.rcsb.org/download/2PCY.pdb)) to this [website](http://biocomp.chem.uw.edu.pl/A3D/). It only allows us to load one structure at a time. But I have hundreds of structure files to load. Is there a way that I can write a script to enable batch submission?

I am open to any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: The likely answer is yes. It would depend on your skills what language you can use. Obviously if you have hundreds of files it might be worth of talk to the owner whenever they can offer you an official interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try their REST interface, see [RESTful service](http://biocomp.chem.uw.edu.pl/A3D/tutorial#collapseRest):

Submitting job from the command line

```
 curl -i -X POST -d \
 '{"email": "john@doe.com", "dynamic": "True", "name": "some project name"}' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
http://biocomp.chem.uw.edu.pl/A3D/RESTful/submit/2pcy/.
```

Line break characters (`\`) added by me.